# Share DLLs between projects

Tags: dll, gac

I have multiple projects in my solution. Each project references other projects. The dlls are quite big and I don't want them to be included in the bin of every project that references it.

What are my options? Ideally I'd like to place them in one location and reference that without needing to include them in my bin folder for each project. The only location I can think of is the GAC. Are there any ideas/suggestions on how you have gotten around this?

Is it possible to use probing paths? Anyone used this before/point me to a tutorial?

I've tried probing paths, get an error when running the application, is this not set up correctly? I've placed my dlls I wish to load from this path in the C:\Projects\myProject\bin folder. And set copy to false in the reference

```
<runtime>
<assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
  <probing privatePath="C:\Projects\myProject\bin"/>
  <dependentAssembly>
    <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.Mvc" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" culture="neutral" />
    <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-3.0.0.0" newVersion="3.0.0.0" />
  </dependentAssembly>
</assemblyBinding>
```

Thanks

Comment: What are your actual concerns with having the DLLs in multiple places?  Constraints on disk space? Build times?  Are they actually big enough that it takes a considerable amount of time to copy them around?

Comment: Not an answer to your question, but if you want the advantages of not having the assemblies in the GAC (updating the DLLs per program instead of globally, reducing possible issues) and at the same time don't want all those assemblies to live in the same folder, then you might want to take a look at [ILMerge](https://research.microsoft.com/en-us/people/mbarnett/ilmerge.aspx) which will merge your assemblies into one. However, the overhead of having multiple assemblies is relatively small.

Comment: Mostly disk space and I want to centralise my dlls, so they're all in one folder, rather than all over the place. The problem with putting them in the GAC is that I have dependencies on 3rd party libraries, some of which are not strongly named which gets a bit tricky.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess what you prefer, is turning off `CopyLocal` when referencing assemblies in Visual Studio

The steps could be:

1. Open `Solution Explorer`
2. Right click at the reference item (project or assembly)
3. Select `Properties` in the context menu.
4. Set `CopyLocal` to `False` (default is true)

Then the references won't be copied to your `project\bin\debug` or etc.

**UPDATE**

You still need to copy your dependency to the same folder, or GAC, or probing paths to run your application.

That is how .Net resolve the assemblies references.

You may refer to [How the Runtime Locates Assemblies](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yx7xezcf.aspx).

**UPDATE 1**

[MSDN Specifying an Assembly's Location](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/4191fzwb%28v=vs.80%29.aspx)

Using the `<probing>` Element
The runtime locates assemblies that do not have a code base by probing. For more information about probing, see How the Runtime Locates Assemblies.
You can use the  element in the application configuration file to specify subdirectories the runtime should search when locating an assembly. The following example shows how to specify directories the runtime should search.

```
<configuration>
  <runtime>
    <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
       <probing privatePath="bin;bin2\subbin;bin3"/>
    </assemblyBinding>
  </runtime>
</configuration>
```

The `privatePath` attribute contains the directories that the runtime should search for assemblies. If the application is located at `C:\Program Files\MyApp`, the runtime will look for assemblies that do not specify a code base in `C:\Program Files\MyApp\Bin`, `C:\Program Files\MyApp\Bin2\Subbin`, and `C:\Program Files\MyApp\Bin3`. The directories specified in `privatePath` must be subdirectories of the application base directory.

Comment: Tried probing paths, get an error when running the app, see edit to question for setup code, any ideas what could be the issue?

Comment: error is Could not load file or assembly 'xxx, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified. It is in that folder, almost like it's not looking at my private path

Comment: Hi, I remembered that the privatepath can only be the directory under your application current folder. For example, your app.exe is under `c:\myproject\bin\debug` , the privatepath can only be something like `c:\myproject\bin\debug\subfolder\ `

Answer (score 1):

You can add referenced libraries to the output folder of start up project only:

1) Right click on starting project, "`Add`", "`Existing Item`". Or `[Shift]+[Alt]+[A]` combination in VS2010 with defaults.

2) Change type selector to "`All files (*)`", find and select your library.

3) Change "Add" selector to "`Add As Link`" and press it.

4) Select a link just added to a project, and in Properties window set "`Copy to Output Directory`" to "`Copy always`". Now, each time you building the solution, this library will be copied to the output folder of your startup project.

5) If you want to restrict copying this dll to the output of project that uses it, right-click on reference in that project, and in Properties window set "`Copy Local`" to false.

**Implications:**

The only place where your referenced dll's will appear will be your start-up project's output directory.

**Disadvantages:**

If you'll change your start-up project, you'll need to add all the links to it again.

Start-up project directory in Solution Explorer becomes messy.

Comment: so if i understand correctly, i would add them to a central folder and then reference them as a link in my startup project and then reference them in all other projects but dont copy to the bin? That means the startup project must reference all my dlls? Hmmm, not really ideal...

Comment: No, startup project must not reference all your dll. It only must add them to the output folder. On the contrary, other projects must reference their dll's but not copying them to their folders. That's exactly what you need, I think

Comment: not following completely, but i'll give it a shot, thanks, what are the implications of this approach? any disadvantages to doing it this way?

Comment: If explanation is not clear - ask. About implications and disadvatages - I'll edit my answer in a minute

Comment: Thanks! I dont think that's going to work for me. I have 2 startup projects I swap between, if i have to add the links each time i swap its going to be a nightmare :|

Comment: Not every time you swap, but every time you create new start-up project. In your case - two times.

Comment: So to confirm - I have a startup project to which I add my reference link for Project1. Then I have Project 2 to which I add a reference to Project 1 and set Copy to local to False. How does Project 2 know to load the dll from the bin folder for the startup project?

Comment: After building solution your start-up project output will contain both Project1.dll and Project2.dll. Project2 will be able to work with Project1.dll because they both will be loaded as application starts. In this example you even don't need to add a link for start-up project, because it already references Project1 and it will copy it to output.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/30581/discussion-between-newbie-86-and-astef)

Comment: thanks for the help, much appreciated! i've decided to go with the probing path solution, it's neater